# Recursion formula keeps returning stack overflow

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I've ran the below code and I think it's correct.  However, it just keeps returning stack overflow.  When I run it in debug mode, I noticed somehow within the function x%y returns y instead of the remainder which is suppose to be 0.  Can someone please help and see why this is?

```
public class test
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println(gcd(50,10));
    }

    static double gcd(double x, double y)
    {
        if (x > y)
        {
            return gcd(y, x);
        }
        else if (y <= x && x%y == 0)
        {
            return y;
        }
        else
        {
            return gcd(y, x%y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of interest, what is gcd?

Comment: Apparently it's an abbrevation for the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).

Comment: Correct, it's the abbreviation of greatest common divisor

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, the implementation causes a stack overflow because for the arguments `50` and `10` the recursive calls reach the first and the last case alternatively, causing an infinite recursion. Apparently the algorithm for determining the greatest common divisor is implemented incorrectly; an elaborate presentation of it can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Procedure). That being said, it might not be a good idea to perform the calculations using the type `double`; I doubt that the division remainder operator `%` will behave as expected due to rounding.